# When to check for database is locked errors in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

On the linux server, where our web app runs, we also have a small app that uses
sqlite (it is written in c).

For performing database actions we use the following commands:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2
sqlite3_bind_text or sqlite3_bind_int
sqlite3_step
sqlite3_finalize
```

Every now and then there was a concurrency situation and I got the following error:

```
database is locked
```

So I thought: "This happens when one process writes a certain record and the
other one is trying to read exactly the same record."

So after every step-command, where this collision could be, I checked for this error. When it happended, I waited a few milliseconds and the tried again.

But the sqlite error "database is locked" still occurred.

So I changed every step command and the code lines after it. Somehow I thought that this "database is locked" error could only occur with the step command.

But the error kept coming.

My question is now:

Do I have to check after any sqlite3 command for "error_code ==5" (database is locked)?

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're receiving error code 5 (busy) you can limit this by using an immediate transaction. If you're able to begin an immediate transaction, SQLite guarantees that you won't receive a busy error until you commit.

Also note that SQLite doesn't have row-level locking. The entire database is locked. Using a WAL journal, you can one writer and multiple readers. With other journaling methods, you can have either one writer, or multiple readers, but not both simultaneously.

[SQLite Documentation on 'SQLITE_BUSY'](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy)